# how to create a splash screen in Flutter with svg image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, splash-screen

I want to create the splash screen in flutter. I have `svg` image file and don't want to convert into `JPG` or `PNG`. Is there any way to create the splash screen with svg image file in Flutter?

**Want to implement the splash screen on Native side.**

**UPDATE WITH SVG CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Uploaded to: SVG Repo, www.svgrepo.com, Generator: SVG Repo Mixer Tools -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg fill="#000000" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 45.917 45.917"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M33.523,28.334c-0.717,1.155-1.498,2.358-2.344,3.608c7.121,1.065,10.766,3.347,10.766,4.481
            c0,1.511-6.459,5.054-18.986,5.054c-12.528,0-18.988-3.543-18.988-5.054c0-1.135,3.645-3.416,10.768-4.481
            c-0.847-1.25-1.628-2.453-2.345-3.608C5.365,29.661,0,32.385,0,36.424c0,5.925,11.551,9.024,22.959,9.024s22.958-3.1,22.958-9.024
            C45.917,32.385,40.553,29.661,33.523,28.334z"/>
        <path d="M22.96,36.047c1.032,0,2.003-0.491,2.613-1.325c3.905-5.33,10.813-15.508,10.813-20.827
            c0-7.416-6.012-13.427-13.427-13.427c-7.417,0-13.427,6.011-13.427,13.427c0,5.318,6.906,15.497,10.812,20.827
            C20.957,35.556,21.928,36.047,22.96,36.047z M17.374,13.63c0-3.084,2.5-5.584,5.585-5.584c3.084,0,5.584,2.5,5.584,5.584
            s-2.5,5.584-5.584,5.584C19.874,19.215,17.374,16.715,17.374,13.63z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Buddy: No not yet

Comment: can u share ur svg file, i may try it on my device first

Comment: I have update svg code. you can make a file and store this code as .svg format.

Comment: @Buddy: I have updated the answer, if you want you can check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found that `packages` to introduce the `SplashScreen` should only accept the image format as `JPG` and `PNG`. After working on the app I have found the solution to make an splashScreen without any package using `SVG` image in Android and iOS both.

Follow the steps below if you want to introduce the `SplashScreen` with `SVG`.

**1.Android**

**Step 1:**

Open the android module from Flutter App in Android Studio separately.

**Step 2:**

Open `res` folder in `drawable` --> include `Vector Asset` ***(Give the path of your `svg` image).***

**Step 3:**

Now make one new drawable `splash_screen_image` with `background color` and include your `Vector Asset Drawable`***(which we included in above step 2)***.

The drawable file `splash_screen_image.xml` should look as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="your color"/>

            <size
                android:width="150dp"
                android:height="150dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:gravity="center" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_svg"/>
</layer-list>
```

**Step 4:**

Now open the `launch_background.xml` and include our new drawable `splash_screen_image.xml`.

Our `launch_background.xml` will look like this as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_screen_image" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

***(Note: If required also do the same changes in `launch_background.xml(v21)`)***

**Step 5:**

Your Android Splash Screen is ready and test it by running flutter app on Android Device.

**2. iOS**

***Note -> Make sure you are working on latest xcode version which supports the `svg` image.***

**Step: 1**

Open iOS module in XCode.

**Step: 2**

Open `Asset` --> `LaunchImage`

**Step: 3**

Drag and drop your `SVG image file` in the space given as 1x, 2x, 3x.

**Step: 4**

Now open the `LaunchScreen.storyBoard` and change the background color as per your requirement.

**Step: 5**

Test your flutter app by opening the application in the iOS device or simulator.

I hope this found very useful.

Comment: this is important note to work (Note: If required also do the same changes in launch_background.xml(v21))

Answer (score -1):

try checking out the flutter_svg from https://pub.dev that should help

Comment: I want splash screen on native side of Android and iOS. With this package it is only possible when we make splash screen in flutter widget.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

follow me by this steps

#### Step1

add flutter_svg to your project by typing this command `flutter pub add flutter_svg`

---

#### Step2

create dart file and inside of it create stateFull widget and put your svg inside

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => SplashScreenState();
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
@override
void initState((){
  Future.delay(Duration(milisecound:500));
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
})
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body:Center(
    child:SvgPicture.string("<SVG></SVG>")
)
);
  }
}
```

#### Step3

now we should modify the main.dart in `MaterialApp` and make home to our splash screen one then we are done

```
MaterialApp(home:SplashScreen());
```

Comment: I want to implement the splash screen native side and not in flutter. Because before `Flutter Engine` loads there is the white screen.

Comment: you  are using flutter then you want to implement in native ?

Comment: To over come the white screen before flutter engine gets loaded.

Comment: the white screen only shown in debug, its dissapres when you export